# Template Matching on OpenCV unity3d c#

Tags: c#, opencv, templates, unity-game-engine, matching

[image]How can I recognize images from video in OpenCV and place 3d Object on that location in unity 3D. Or I want to create a cascade file in Xml. I create an Xml file but it does not work.

Please help me, I am not getting any solution of that problem:

Like Image give below - If i want to detect lips from Image and position on lips in unity vector2 cordinates .

Comment: It's not likely that someone reading this has done this exact thing and knows the exact solution to it. In fact, it's not likely many people, who might've done something similar, will understand what you mean. I suggest you post the code you've tried to make it work and perhaps furthering explaining what you want to achieve.

Comment: Yes , you are right.